# Inserting sql data from java issue

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to insert this data using java into mysql and it say's that there is something wrong with the sql syntax but I haven't been able to figure it out. Any help would be awesome.

```
stmt = conn.createStatement();
         String sql;
         String fname = "Kyle";
         String lname = "Longrich";

         String insert = "INSERT INTO 'hospital', 'test' ('Firstname', 'Lastname') VALUES ('" + fname + "' , '" + lname + "')";

         stmt.executeUpdate(insert);
```

Comment: `"it say's that there is something wrong with the sql syntax"` - It doesn't say anything more specific than that?  Usually it tells you where the syntax error is.  Why are you specifying two tables?  Why are you using single-quotes around table and column names?  Why are you concatenating values instead of using parameters?

Comment: Concatenating values is a bad idea. Please use prepared statement instead.

Comment: (1) You can't insert into 2 tables at once. (2) Table names and column names are escaped using backticks ` and not single quotes (those are for strings).

Answer (score 1):

At a quick glance I see a couple of errors:

- You're specifying two tables
- You're treating identifiers (table/column names) as strings

Try this instead:

```
String insert = "INSERT INTO hospital.test (Firstname, Lastname) VALUES ('" + fname + "' , '" + lname + "')";
```

Or if you need to specify identifiers with back-ticks (which is never a bad idea, really):

```
String insert = "INSERT INTO `hospital`.`test` (`Firstname`, `Lastname`) VALUES ('" + fname + "' , '" + lname + "')";
```

Additionally, you may want to look into using query parameters with prepared statements.  In this particular case what you have isn't a SQL injection vulnerability since you're still using hard-coded literal values, but this style of string concatenation to build SQL queries can and will lead to SQL injection vulnerabilities when you no longer control the values being used.

Comment: hospital is the data base and test is the tabel

Comment: @user5890889: In that case the notation would likely be `hospital.test`.  I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert that same data into two different tables, you must execute two different statements.

```
INSERT INTO hospital ('Firstname', 'Lastname') VALUES (..)
```

and

```
INSERT INTO test ('Firstname', 'Lastname') VALUES (..)
```

You're not able to merge both statements together. Apart from that the SQL looks valid.